# How to generate valid PDF/A file using kpfonts?

Tags: kpfonts, pdf-a, pdfx

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\sffamily\scshape%
\blindtext%

\end{document}
```

Although it successfully compiles to a pdf file, the pdf file does not comply PDF/A standard. Validating it against https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx, I got:

```
Validating file "test.pdf" for conformance level pdfa-1b
The width for character 68 in font 'IYLNAZ+Sf-Kp-Sc-Regular' does not match.
The document does not conform to the requested standard.
The document contains fonts without embedded font programs or encoding information (CMAPs).
The document does not conform to the PDF/A-1b standard.
Done.
```

Comment: Since 68 may relate to D I note there is a potential compatability warning in the documentation and a special command for compatibility "noDcommand (M.) kpfonts doesn’t load its \D command" it may be worth a try ? but don't ask me how to set it I just look at documentation not use it